# Unable to close/delete file from python or OS

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to delete an excel file from my computer but it will not let me, and keeps saying that the file is open/in use by python. I have tried using f.close() methods and os.remove() with no luck. I can't find any temporary files in the Excel default local file location either. I really am at a loss as to why I am unable to close or delete this file through python or otherwise.

Comment: What the OS is telling you is that there is a process somewhere with that file open. The only description it has for that process is "python", but that doesn't mean that any Python program can take over and close/delete the file. So this is really a case of ["How do I find/kill the process that has my file open?"](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but if you just need to delete one specific file, why not either end the python process (task manager -> kill task) or restart your computer? That should let you manually delete it.

Comment: IMSoP Your answer and thread provided solved my problem. I was able to find and kill the process through the Process Manager.